# Understanding Assembly Binder Log

Tags: c#, .net, fuslogvw

The log from a failed bind looks like this:
[BinderLogEntry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPiOv.png)

This seems to be saying that 12.0.0.0 was converted to 12.0.3.0 (which is what I specified and wanted), but then  seems to be using 12.0.0.0 (and saying it can't find it).

The properties of the Newtonsoft.json.dll look like this:
[image]

Why is it still looking for 12.0.0.0 ?

Comment: It's not, it's looking for 12.0.3.0, but found 12.0.0.0 in your UpdateRunCalcs/bin/release folder

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer thanks, that wasn't clear to me from the message. Now I've added the properties tab from the file in that directory - seems to be saying it's 12.0.3.x - is that not the case?